# Why if ZF is consistent, neither the axiom of choice nor the generalized continuum hypothesis cannot be disproved?

Tags: set-theory

I think it's because since by godel incompleteness theorem ZF cannot be proved to be consistent (and therefore it can't also be disproved to be consistent the consequent of the implication "if ZF is consistent, then so is ZFC and the generalized continuum hypothesis" cannot hold (since the antecedent cannot be proved to be true) or equivalently contrapositive of the implication "if ZFC and the generalized continuum hypothesis are not consistent, then ZF is not consistent" in this case since the consequent cannot be proved or disproved, one cannot say anything about the whole implication, correct?

Answer (score 5):

The incompleteness theorem is the reason why we need to talk about this statement as an implication, yes. But it's not the reason why this statement is true.

For it to be true vacuously you'd need to be able to prove that $\sf ZF$ is inconsistent, but we didn't find any such proof yet. So what happens if it is consistent? Gödel showed that given any model of $\sf ZF$, there is a very canonical model which we can "carve out" of the given model, and in this canonical model $\sf ZF + AC + GCH$ holds. This model is called the constructible universe, and it is often denoted by $L$.

Moreover, this model is so nice, that we can actually translate this proof to a syntactic derivation. Namely, if you give me a proof of contradiction from $\sf ZFC$, I can follow Gödel and convert it to a proof of contradiction from $\sf ZF$ alone.